# Is it possible to see other layers while scaling an image in Gimp?

Tags: gimp, scaling, image-transparency

I have 2 layers in Gimp:

1. an image of human and environment
2. bounding polyline

I'm trying to scale the image to put human in the bounding polyline, but when I use a scale tool I see only the image I'm currently scaling but not the bounding polyline from the second layer.

I've tried to make the 1st layer half transparent, but this didn't help, when scaling it becomes non-transparent.

How can I perform scaling and see the bounding polyline from the other layer?

Gimp 2.6.10, Windows XP

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things might work:

Pull guides from the edges of the workspace, they're blue lines. Make guides to show you where the polyline is.

Temporarily move the polyline layer to the top, make it somewhat transparent. Then scale the layer beneath it from the menu with pixels incrementally.